# Set aspect ratio of image without src

Tags: javascript, html, image, image-processing

I use images created on the fly to maintain the aspect ratio of boxes with a fixed height.  Image sources are set as data-urls provided from a canvas with a given width and height, the images are then attached to divs which can contain any content, have any height, and still maintain a fixed aspect ratio.

This works well, however, on slower phones with less memory the large number of data-urls on the page can start to be a little bit of a drag.  Some of the ratios can't be reduced below a certain point resulting in relatively large canvases.

**Is there any way to set the ratio of an img element without setting its source?**  Is there any way to set the source to a format that is an truly empty image with only a width and height?

EDIT:  The snippet below throws an error - iframe restrictions, probably having to do with making images.  You can see an error free version over at [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/RerrRQ).

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

function addRatioBox(width, height = 1) {
 const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
 
 const img = new Image(width, height);
 const box = document.createElement("div");
 
 cvs.width = width;
 cvs.height = height;
 
 img.src = cvs.toDataURL("image/png");
 
 box.appendChild(img);
 box.className = "ratioBox";
 
 wrapper.appendChild(box);
}

addRatioBox(1);
addRatioBox(4, 3);
addRatioBox(16, 9);
addRatioBox(2, 1);
```

```css
.ratioBox {
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.ratioBox img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}




/* just a whole bunch of stuff to make things prettier from here on down */

.wrapper {
  background: #556;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background: #334;
}

.ratioBox:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: These pictures that are created "on the fly", are they cropped versions of non-trivial images or are they something that could be generated without image data?

Comment: @patrickroberts they're made from entirely blank canvas elements

Comment: don't use images for layout, that hasn't been needed since 1999

Comment: @dandavis okay so what's your solution?

Comment: @SandyGifford using a [pseudo-element](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/#article-header-id-6) might be more appropriate.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I use that trick for when height needs to be based on width - it's a nifty one, but since it hinges on padding top/bottom being a percent of width, it won't work for this scenario.

Comment: @SandyGifford that's a good point... all of these solutions calculate height based on width, not width based on height. I'll try some things out when I have more time to look into it but right now I don't have any suggestions.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yeah - thinking I might just have to deal with it as-is.  It's only really a problem on older phones so it's not the end of the world, but I figured it was worth a shot asking.

Comment: @SandyGifford you could try the pseudo-element trick with a [`rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate) transform, but that's the only thing I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts not having any luck with that approach either (see [here](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/mzPyaj)).  Padding is still based on an unset width :(